# Querying a table with LONG column

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I'm writing a function searching for a text in the dictionary view ALL_VIEWS. The column of interest, called TEXT, is of LONG(!) datatype and this creates a major problem: I can't query a view text pattern. Without help of procedural code executed on server, I would have to fetch all the view records and filter the ones of interest on client. This solution is no go for performance reasons.

A better alternative is calling anonymous PL/SQL block performing the query against ALL_VIEWS, filtering all interesting views, and returning result set to the client. There are several possibilities how to do that:

1. Create temporary table, and return a cursor iterating it
2. Create collection datatype, and bind it as return value
3. Dump the filtered records into DBMS_OUTPUT, and examine it in the followup JDBC call

An important limitation is that I'm not allowed to create any database object. Also in the first case there has to be create temporary table permission.

For second case I tried the following:

```
    String sql = "declare\n"+
            "  l_search varchar2(1000) := 'union';\n"+
            "  l_char varchar2(32767);\n"+
            "  TYPE strtbl IS TABLE OF varchar2(1000) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER \n"+
            "  l_st strtbl; \n"+
            "  i integer; \n"+
            "begin\n"+
            "  i := 1;"+
            "  for rec in (select * from all_views where rownum < 10)\n"+
            "  loop\n"+
            "    l_char := rec.text;\n"+
            "    if (instr(l_char, l_search) > 0) then\n"+
            "      l_st(i) := 'Match: ' || rec.owner || '.' || rec.view_name;\n"+
            "      i := i+1;\n"+
            "    end if;\n"+
            "  end loop;\n"+
            "  ? := l_st;\n"+
            "end;";
    final CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(sql);
    cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.ARRAY);
    cs.execute();
    // cs.getObject(1);  // cast to array, etc.
```

However, JDBC refuses to bind the output parameter; this is where I'm stuck.

Finally, even though the third solution is feasible, it is ugly beyond my acceptance threshold.

Comment: Maybe `select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('VIEW', rec.view_name) from dual` is more suitable for you. Result is a `CLOB` which has much better support than `LONG`

Comment: I can't use DBMS_METADATA for searching across multiple views. (Technically, I can, but not performance wise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API on OracleCallableStatement:
[registerIndexTableOutParameter](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html#registerIndexTableOutParameter_int__int__int__int_)
which can be used to define an OUT parameter as a PLSQL associative array. Then there is a [getPlsqlIndexTable](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html#getPlsqlIndexTable_int_) method to retrieve the value once the procedure has finished executing. In your case the object returned should be a String[].